# Pimcore Mandatory Metadata

Tags: metadata, assets, pimcore, pimcore-v5

is there an option to set some metadata from assets as a mandatory field ?

For data-objects you can create mandatory fields, but I need this option for the metadata of the asstes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in option. But you can validate the data either in the frontend or the backend and disallow saving if not all required metadata is filled in.

---

[Backend validation](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Event_API_and_Event_Manager.html)

You could for example throw a new Exception in a pre-update event listener:

```
throw new \Pimcore\Model\Element\ValidationException("This is your custom error message", 1234);
```

[List of all Asset Events](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/lib/Event/AssetEvents.php)

---

You could also check the data in the frontend as described here:

[Frontend validation](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Bundle_Developers_Guide/Plugin_Backend_UI.html#page_Validate-Pimcore-Object-s-Data-in-frontend-before-saving)